# Регулярное выражение на поиск всех букв

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

На многоязычном сайте нужно проверять одно поле на корректность введенных данных. Строка должна состоять только из букв. Как регулярным выражением захватить русский, немецкий, французский, английский и испанский?

/^[^\W]+$/i - не работает.

Кодировка UTF-8.

PHP5

Comment: Поддержка юникодовости зависит от реализации регулярных выражений. Вы хоть скажите, какой язык\библиотека используется?

Comment: Язык php5.

Comment: Ох, там всё очень сложно. Сейчас постараюсь подробно ответить. Для начала: \w совпадает с любым альфа-символом. \W совпадает с чем угодно, кроме альфа-символа. Чувствуете? Ваш регэксп совпадёт с кучей всякой дряни!

Comment: Именно по этому и спрашиваю. Знаю что эта регулярка не то.

Comment: Не, там всё, правда, очень сложно… Нет сил подробно всё описать. Если какие-то конкретные вопросы — спрашивайте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Нужен модификатор `u`
2. `/^(?>\pL\pM*)+$/u`

---

- `\pL` совпадёт с любой буквой: ц, w, á
- `\pM*` совпадёт с любым числом модификаторов — это нужно, поскольку буква á может быть записана как один символ, а может быть записана как два: á.

Comment: Это выражение совпадёт с последовательностью валидных символов Юникода. По языкам, сами понимаете, никак не отфильтровать. Можно только забацать хитрое выражение, которое будет совпадать по алфавитам — кириллица и латиница (ну, чтобы иероглифы исключить).

Comment: Отлично! Работает. Спасибо. Про языки это уже не так важно.

Comment: Я изменил в регулярном выражении : на >. Так правильнее.

Answer (score 0):

Я решал для многих языков примерно следующей схемой:

$lang[] = 'абвгдеёжзиклмн...эюяАБВ...ЭЮЯ'

$lang[] = 'abcde...ßABCDE...';

...

$lang[]...

preg_ match_all('/[a-zA-Z'.implode('', $lang).']/is', $str, $out);

И это единственная схема, которая работала на ура, во всех остальных были косяки с пониманием каких-либо символов языка.

Comment: Это просто значит, что Вы недостаточно терпеливы, чтобы понять суть происходящего. Естественно, костыль придумать всегда можно. Но если бы Вы разобрались с тем, как работает Юникод в регэкспах, жить стало бы значительно веселее ;).

Comment: Когда есть время, тогда я его трачу на подобные вещи, а когда проект нужно сдать "вчера", то времени нет и приходится извращаться :)

Answer (score 0):

Есть фильтры на php, копните в эту сторону, статья была на хабре.
По сути, это регулярки обернутые в функции. Скорее всего есть фильтр на буквы.

Answer (score -2):

Как я понял, проблема решена. Так что только вдогонку.

**/^[^W]+$/i - не работает.**

Так вроде и не должен. Это то ли поиск строк из не-**W**, то ли не из **W** и **\**.
В [] надо указывать символы, диапазоны или классы. Сам я с php дела не имел, но гугл подсказал:

POSIX Character Class Definitions
Value
Meaning
[:digit:]
[:alnum:]
[:alpha:]
[:blank:]
[:xdigit:]
[:punct:]
[:print:]
[:space:]
[:graph:]
[:upper:]
[:lower:]
[:cntrl:]

Comment: @kirelagin Пожалуйста, будьте всегда вежливы. Если Вы несогласны с мнением участника, проголосуйте против его ответа, или просигнальте тревогой.

Comment: @ХэшКод просто проголосовать обычно бывает недостаточно — надо же объяснить в чём ошибка и предложить способы восполнения недостающих знаний в обсуждаемой области. Мне показалось, я сделал и то и другое, причём в рамках приличия.

Comment: Флейм меня мало трогает. А вот то, на что я пытался указать - различие между "\xxx" и классами символов "[]" - осталось за кадром. Когда-то давно у меня самого этот момент вызывал затруднения.

@ХэшКод Я здесь новичок и если бы знал как - ответил бы e-mail'ом

Comment: @alexlz меня тоже флейм трогает мало, а вот Ваше явное незнание того, что означает «\w» — трогает. Ответьте, пожалуйста, емейлом. Если щёлкнуть по моей подписи, откроется страничка с информацией. Я не знаю, как тут устроены настройки приватности, но, если Вам там не видет мой емейл, то уж адрес сайта виден точно, а на нём уже доаольно легко найти и адрес. Обсудим регулярные выражения.